# How to hide header and footer in WKWebView using Js and ios-14

Tags: ios, swift

How to hide header and footer in WKWebView in swift in IOS 14 I am using below code  for loadiing thr website inside webview.

```
 webview.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: "myURLHere)!))
```

Comment: Define "header" and "footer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegate function while loading the website like

```
self.webview.uiDelegate = self
webview.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: 'url here')!))
```

and then inside the delegate method use following code.

```
   public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"header_id\").style.display='none';document.getElementById(\"footer_id\").style.display='none';", completionHandler: { (res, error) -> Void in
        //Here you can check for results if needed (res) or whether the execution was successful (error)
    })
```

}

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code using CSS**

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let cssString = "header {display: none;}"
                   let script = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
                webView.evaluateJavaScript(script,
                        completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in
                    print(error)
                    webView.isHidden = false
                        })
                let cssString1 = "footer {display: none;}"
                   let script1 = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(cssString1)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
                webView.evaluateJavaScript(script1,
                        completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in
                    webView.isHidden = false
                        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `WKUserContentController` to inject script to hide `header`, `footer` or something which you want

```swift
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
let script = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = 'header {display: none;}'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
let scriptInjection = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
contentController.addUserScript(scriptInjection)
        
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.websiteDataStore = .nonPersistent()
configuration.userContentController = contentController
let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```